# Opencv multiprocessing in python - queue sync

Tags: python, opencv, multiprocessing

I am a beginner with multiprocessing in Python. I am developing a multiprocessing script for OpenCV, since my computer does not succeed in real-time processing of OpenCV frames.
I aim at loading and processing frames in the main process, and displaying them using a child process. My problem is that I do not understand **how to build the display loop from the queued frames**. Can someone please help?

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from Queue import Empty
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import cv2.cv as cv
import numpy as np

def image_display(taskqueue):
   cv2.namedWindow ('image_display', cv2.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
   while True:
      if taskqueue.get()==None:
         continue
      else:
         image = taskqueue.get()
         im = Image.fromstring(image['mode'], image['size'], image['pixels'])
         num_im = np.asarray(im)
         cv2.imshow ('image_display', num_im)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   taskqueue = Queue()
   vidFile = cv2.VideoCapture('doppler.wmv')
   p = Process(target=image_display, args=(taskqueue,))
   p.start()
   while True:
      flag, image=vidFile.read()
      if flag == 0:
         break
      im = Image.fromarray(image)
      im_dict = {
      'pixels': im.tostring(),
      'size': im.size,
      'mode': im.mode,
      }
      taskqueue.put(im_dict)

p.join()
cv.DestroyAllWindows()
```

### **EDIT**

Thanks to the answers, I was able to find the problem. Below is a modified script in which I **slowed my loops** on purpose and **added an outqueue for debugging**. It appears that although the frames captured with  `vidFile.read()` are indeed passed as numpy arrays through the queue and are then passed unmodified as argument to `cv2.imshow()`,**`cv2.imshow()` refuses to display the image for an unknown reason**. Any help to fix that issue would be immensly appreciated!

modified code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from Queue import Empty
import cv2
import cv2.cv as cv
import numpy as np
import time

def image_display(taskqueue, outqueue):
   cv2.namedWindow ('image_display', cv2.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
   while True:
      try:
         outqueue.put('trying')
         time.sleep(1)
         image = taskqueue.get()
         outqueue.put(image)
         cv2.imshow('image_display', image)
      except:
         continue



if __name__ == '__main__':
   taskqueue = Queue()
   outqueue = Queue()
   vidFile = cv2.VideoCapture('doppler.wmv')
   p = Process(target=image_display, args=(taskqueue, outqueue))
   p.start()
   while True:
      print outqueue.get()
      flag, image=vidFile.read()
      if flag == 0:
         break
      taskqueue.put(image)
      time.sleep(0.010)

p.join()
cv.DestroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Like I already mentioned in my Answer below, all you have to do is add ``cv2.waitKey(10)`` right after ``imshow()``. And remove the ``sleep(1)`` above as there's no need to sleep in the spawned process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work (explanation of changes below):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from Queue import Empty
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import cv2.cv as cv
import numpy as np

def image_display(taskqueue):
   cv2.namedWindow ('image_display', cv2.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
   while True:

      image = taskqueue.get()              # Added
      if image is None:  break             # Added
      cv2.imshow ('image_display', image)  # Added
      cv2.waitKey(10)                      # Added
      continue                             # Added

      if taskqueue.get()==None:
         continue
      else:
         image = taskqueue.get()
         im = Image.fromstring(image['mode'], image['size'], image['pixels'])
         num_im = np.asarray(im)
         cv2.imshow ('image_display', num_im)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   taskqueue = Queue()
   vidFile = cv2.VideoCapture('doppler.wmv')
   p = Process(target=image_display, args=(taskqueue,))
   p.start()
   while True:
      flag, image=vidFile.read()

      taskqueue.put(image)  # Added
      import time           # Added
      time.sleep(0.010)     # Added
      continue              # Added

      if flag == 0:
         break
      im = Image.fromarray(image)
      im_dict = {
      'pixels': im.tostring(),
      'size': im.size,
      'mode': im.mode,
      }
      taskqueue.put(im_dict)

taskqueue.put(None)
p.join()
cv.DestroyAllWindows()
```

I tried to make minimal changes to your code by just adding lines (lines containing comments `# Added`):

1) Just put the image itself (the original NumPy array) on the queue.

2) Pause a little bit in the master process before reading another frame. You need this so as not to overrun the queue, because `imshow()` in the spawned process may take a bit longer since it's calling X. You might need to increase this value (in seconds) depending on your system.

3) Spawned process has to do the `waitKey()` after every `imshow()`.

4) Master process puts the special `None` image on the queue when it's done.

Comment: I achieved something very similar to you while searching on my own, but cv2.imshow() will not display the images, and your solution seems to have the same problem! The argument passed to it (image) is indeed a numpy array though, and seems to have the right format. I do not understand the problem... any ideas? BTW thank you very much for teaching me that numpy arrays can be passed through the queue!

Comment: Hmm.. as is, the code above works for me. The only thing I can think of is that the file ``doppler.wmv`` is not legit. Does it play with MPlayer or another video player?

Comment: The file plays in windows media player without problems. I tried another file (.mp4), but the result is the same. Very strange...

Comment: If you have a webcam, try replacing ``cv2.VideoCapture('doppler.wmv')`` with ``cv2.VideoCapture(0)`` and see if you can stream your webcam instead. Also, just to reiterate, try increasing the `sleep` value--basically, the slower your system, the longer you should delay before reading the next frame.

Comment: AHA! Streaming the webcam works perfectly! Thank you for your help! Now, I have to look into my files to understand what is going on...